# Esp8266 Arduino smart connect

Tags: wifi, esp8266

Below i have an example of a temperature sensor.What i need to be able to set the username an password dynamically before connecting to my home router.It would ask me for the ssid and password for example.example. Ive seen a couple of posts about this with no definitive code to show how it would work.If anyone has experience with this could they comment here please.

```
#include 
#include 
#include
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 8
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

#define SSID "[YOUR_SSID]"
#define PASS "[YOUR_PASSWORD]"
#define IP "184.106.153.149" // thingspeak.com
String GET = "GET /update?key=[THINGSPEAK_KEY]&field1=";


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(5000);
  if(Serial.find("OK")){
    connectWiFi();
  }
}

void loop(){
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float tempC = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  tempC = DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC);
  char buffer[10];
  String tempF = dtostrf(tempC, 4, 1, buffer);
  updateTemp(tempF);
  delay(60000);
}

void updateTemp(String tenmpF){
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += IP;
  cmd += "\",80";
  Serial.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);
  if(Serial.find("Error")){
    return;
  }
  cmd = GET;
  cmd += tenmpF;
  cmd += "\r\n";
  Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
  Serial.println(cmd.length());
  if(Serial.find(">")){
    Serial.print(cmd);
  }else{
    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  }
}


boolean connectWiFi(){
  Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  delay(2000);
  String cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"";
  cmd+=SSID;
  cmd+="\",\"";
  cmd+=PASS;
  cmd+="\"";
  Serial.println(cmd);
  delay(5000);
  if(Serial.find("OK")){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you need some sort of way to input the username and password so you'll need to use a SoftwareSerial to connect to your computer through an FTDI in order to communicate the information over a COM port.

Comment: Without software serial,setting up a temporary access point for example and entering the details on a web page which will then disconnect and reconnect to the home router,is this possible ?

Comment: Yea, assuming the temp access point has the same user and pass all the time.  Just connect to that, enter the permissions through the web-portal and have the webapp send the new information to your device then connect to that.  You'll have considerably more back-end work to do though since you need to set up a little web-app/server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cobbled together, from the library examples, a program to log temperature and humidity to an MQTT server. The SSID/password, MQTT server and port, and the MQTT publish path can all be set at run time. Once they are set, the device will remember and re-use the settings next time it boots.

I am using the Arduino IDE to program an ESP8266-01. It, in turn, talks to a DHT11 sensor for temperature and humidity data.

The program is found at https://github.com/PabluskiNC/TempHumidityLogger

```
    #include <FS.h>                   //this needs to be first, or it all crashes and burns...

    #include "DHT.h"
    #define DHTPIN 2
    #define DHTTYPE DHT11
    DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

    //needed for library
    #include <DNSServer.h>
    #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
    #include <WiFiManager.h>          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

    #include <ArduinoJson.h>          //https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

    #include <PubSubClient.h>
    WiFiClient espClient;
    PubSubClient client(espClient);
    long mqtt_lastMsg = 0;
    char mqtt_msg[50];
    int  mqtt_value = 0;

    //define your default values here, if there are different values in config.json, they are overwritten.
    char mqtt_server[40];
    char mqtt_port[6] = "1883";
    char mqtt_topic[34] = "OutTopic";

    //flag for saving data
    bool shouldSaveConfig = false;

    //callback notifying us of the need to save config
    void saveConfigCallback () {
      Serial.println("Should save config");
      shouldSaveConfig = true;
    }


    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.println();

      //clean FS, for testing
      //SPIFFS.format();

      //read configuration from FS json
      Serial.println("mounting FS...");

      if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("mounted file system");
        if (SPIFFS.exists("/config.json")) {
          //file exists, reading and loading
          Serial.println("reading config file");
          File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");
          if (configFile) {
            Serial.println("opened config file");
            size_t size = configFile.size();
            // Allocate a buffer to store contents of the file.
            std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);

            configFile.readBytes(buf.get(), size);
            DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
            JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.parseObject(buf.get());
            json.printTo(Serial);
            if (json.success()) {
              Serial.println("\nparsed json");

              strcpy(mqtt_server, json["mqtt_server"]);
              strcpy(mqtt_port, json["mqtt_port"]);
              strcpy(mqtt_topic, json["mqtt_topic"]);

            } else {
              Serial.println("failed to load json config");
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        Serial.println("failed to mount FS");
      }
      //end read



      // The extra parameters to be configured (can be either global or just in the setup)
      // After connecting, parameter.getValue() will get you the configured value
      // id/name placeholder/prompt default length
      WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_server("server", "mqtt server", mqtt_server, 40);
      WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_port("port", "mqtt port", mqtt_port, 5);
      WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_topic("topic", "mqtt topic", mqtt_topic, 32);

      //WiFiManager
      //Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around
      WiFiManager wifiManager;

      //set config save notify callback
      wifiManager.setSaveConfigCallback(saveConfigCallback);

      //set static ip
      //wifiManager.setSTAStaticIPConfig(IPAddress(10, 0, 1, 99), IPAddress(10, 0, 1, 1), IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));

      //add all your parameters here
      wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_server);
      wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_port);
      wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_topic);

      //reset settings - for testing
      //wifiManager.resetSettings();

      //set minimu quality of signal so it ignores AP's under that quality
      //defaults to 8%
      //wifiManager.setMinimumSignalQuality();

      //sets timeout until configuration portal gets turned off
      //useful to make it all retry or go to sleep
      //in seconds
      //wifiManager.setTimeout(120);

      //fetches ssid and pass and tries to connect
      //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
      //here  "AutoConnectAP"
      //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
      if (!wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP", "password")) {
        Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
        delay(3000);
        //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
        ESP.reset();
        delay(5000);
      }

      //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
      Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");

      //read updated parameters
      strcpy(mqtt_server, custom_mqtt_server.getValue());
      strcpy(mqtt_port, custom_mqtt_port.getValue());
      strcpy(mqtt_topic, custom_mqtt_topic.getValue());

      //save the custom parameters to FS
      if (shouldSaveConfig) {
        Serial.println("saving config");
        DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
        JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.createObject();
        json["mqtt_server"] = mqtt_server;
        json["mqtt_port"] = mqtt_port;
        json["mqtt_topic"] = mqtt_topic;

        File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w");
        if (!configFile) {
          Serial.println("failed to open config file for writing");
        }

        json.printTo(Serial);
        json.printTo(configFile);
        configFile.close();
        //end save
      }

      client.setServer(mqtt_server, stringToNumber(mqtt_port));
      client.setCallback(callback);
      Serial.println("local ip");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      dht.begin();
    }

    int stringToNumber(String thisString) {
      int i, value, length;
      length = thisString.length();
      char blah[(length + 1)];
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        blah[i] = thisString.charAt(i);
      }
      blah[i] = 0;
      value = atoi(blah);
      return value;
    }

    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
      Serial.print("Message arrived [");
      Serial.print(topic);
      Serial.print("] ");
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
      }
      Serial.println();

      // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
      if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
        digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
        // but actually the LED is on; this is because
        // it is acive low on the ESP-01)
      } else {
        digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
      }

    }

    void reconnect() {
      // Loop until we're reconnected
      while (!client.connected()) {
        Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
        Serial.print(mqtt_server);
        Serial.print(":");
        Serial.print(mqtt_port);
        Serial.print("...");
        // Attempt to connect
        if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
          Serial.println("connected");
          // Once connected, publish an announcement...
          client.publish(mqtt_topic, "Reconnected");
          // ... and resubscribe
          //client.subscribe("inTopic");
        } else {
          Serial.print("failed, rc=");
          Serial.print(client.state());
          Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
          // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
          delay(5000);
        }
      }
    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

      float h = dht.readHumidity();
      float t = dht.readTemperature();
      if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
      } else {
        Serial.print("Temp:");
        Serial.print(t);
        Serial.print( "*C  Humidity:");
        Serial.print(h);
        Serial.println("%");
        if (!client.connected()) {
          reconnect();
        }
        client.loop();

        //long now = millis();
        //if (now - mqtt_lastMsg > 2000) {
        //  lastMsg = now;
        //  ++mqtt_value;
        char temp[7];
        dtostrf(t,4,2,temp); //convert float to char
        snprintf (mqtt_msg, 50, "%s C", temp);
        //  Serial.print("Publish message: ");
        //  Serial.println(msg);
        //  client.publish(mqtt_topic, msg);
        //}
        char pub_topic[34];
        strcpy(pub_topic,mqtt_topic);
        strcat(pub_topic,"/temperature");
        client.publish( pub_topic , mqtt_msg);
        Serial.print("Publish: ");
        Serial.print(pub_topic);
        Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.println(mqtt_msg);

        dtostrf(h,4,2,temp); //convert float to char
        snprintf (mqtt_msg, 50, "%s %", temp);

        strcpy(pub_topic,mqtt_topic);
        strcat(pub_topic,"/humidity");
        client.publish(pub_topic,mqtt_msg);
        Serial.print("Publish: ");
        Serial.print(pub_topic);
        Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.println(mqtt_msg);
      }
      delay(5000);
    }
```

Comment: This is a nice piece of code.Great Job

Answer (score 2):

The following code can do what you want ([source](https://gist.github.com/dogrocker/f998dde4dbac923c47c1)), all that is needed is to combine it with the sensor code. The default behaviour is to create an access point when it can't connect to the eeprom stored WiFi station but you can modify it to trigger with a button/jumper or any other way you prefer.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const char* ssid = "test";
const char* passphrase = "test";
String st;
String content;
int statusCode;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Startup");
  // read eeprom for ssid and pass
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM ssid");
  String esid;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
      esid += char(EEPROM.read(i));
    }
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(esid);
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM pass");
  String epass = "";
  for (int i = 32; i < 96; ++i)
    {
      epass += char(EEPROM.read(i));
    }
  Serial.print("PASS: ");
  Serial.println(epass);  
  if ( esid.length() > 1 ) {
      WiFi.begin(esid.c_str(), epass.c_str());
      if (testWifi()) {
        launchWeb(0);
        return;
      } 
  }
  setupAP();
}

bool testWifi(void) {
  int c = 0;
  Serial.println("Waiting for Wifi to connect");  
  while ( c < 20 ) {
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { return true; } 
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(WiFi.status());    
    c++;
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connect timed out, opening AP");
  return false;
} 

void launchWeb(int webtype) {
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("SoftAP IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  createWebServer(webtype);
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started"); 
}

void setupAP(void) {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n == 0)
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  else
  {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
      Serial.print(")");
      Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE)?" ":"*");
      delay(10);
     }
  }
  Serial.println(""); 
  st = "<ol>";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      st += "<li>";
      st += WiFi.SSID(i);
      st += " (";
      st += WiFi.RSSI(i);
      st += ")";
      st += (WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE)?" ":"*";
      st += "</li>";
    }
  st += "</ol>";
  delay(100);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, passphrase, 6);
  Serial.println("softap");
  launchWeb(1);
  Serial.println("over");
}

void createWebServer(int webtype)
{
  if ( webtype == 1 ) {
    server.on("/", []() {
        IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
        String ipStr = String(ip[0]) + '.' + String(ip[1]) + '.' + String(ip[2]) + '.' + String(ip[3]);
        content = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>Hello from ESP8266 at ";
        content += ipStr;
        content += "<p>";
        content += st;
        content += "</p><form method='get' action='setting'><label>SSID: </label><input name='ssid' length=32><input name='pass' length=64><input type='submit'></form>";
        content += "</html>";
        server.send(200, "text/html", content);  
    });
    server.on("/setting", []() {
        String qsid = server.arg("ssid");
        String qpass = server.arg("pass");
        if (qsid.length() > 0 && qpass.length() > 0) {
          Serial.println("clearing eeprom");
          for (int i = 0; i < 96; ++i) { EEPROM.write(i, 0); }
          Serial.println(qsid);
          Serial.println("");
          Serial.println(qpass);
          Serial.println("");

          Serial.println("writing eeprom ssid:");
          for (int i = 0; i < qsid.length(); ++i)
            {
              EEPROM.write(i, qsid[i]);
              Serial.print("Wrote: ");
              Serial.println(qsid[i]); 
            }
          Serial.println("writing eeprom pass:"); 
          for (int i = 0; i < qpass.length(); ++i)
            {
              EEPROM.write(32+i, qpass[i]);
              Serial.print("Wrote: ");
              Serial.println(qpass[i]); 
            }    
          EEPROM.commit();
          content = "{\"Success\":\"saved to eeprom... reset to boot into new wifi\"}";
          statusCode = 200;
        } else {
          content = "{\"Error\":\"404 not found\"}";
          statusCode = 404;
          Serial.println("Sending 404");
        }
        server.send(statusCode, "application/json", content);
    });
  } else if (webtype == 0) {
    server.on("/", []() {
      IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
      String ipStr = String(ip[0]) + '.' + String(ip[1]) + '.' + String(ip[2]) + '.' + String(ip[3]);
      server.send(200, "application/json", "{\"IP\":\"" + ipStr + "\"}");
    });
    server.on("/cleareeprom", []() {
      content = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>";
      content += "<p>Clearing the EEPROM</p></html>";
      server.send(200, "text/html", content);
      Serial.println("clearing eeprom");
      for (int i = 0; i < 96; ++i) { EEPROM.write(i, 0); }
      EEPROM.commit();
      WiFi.disconnect();
    });
  }
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

The configuration access point ssid and password are set in

```
const char* ssid = "test";
const char* passphrase = "test";
```

The default IP is 192.168.4.1. When you open it from a browser you see a screen which lists the available WiFi stations (ESP8266 scan result), the signal strength and an asterisk on locked stations. There are also two text boxes where you enter the ssid and password of the station you want to connect to and submit:

[image]

Note that there is a [link to a similar library](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager) in the comments of the source link, that didn't work for me but you can try it.

Comment: The WifiManager is pretty good, but my own testing reveals it needs to mature a bit.  It has trouble authenticating to my WiFi; but keep your eyes on it